# Oracle how to compare subset in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, subset

I have one table (T1) with 3 columns: id, category, sector

```
id, category, sector 
1    1         2 
10   1         3 
10   5         4
20   1         3
20   5         4
20   7         8
```

I want a query that return the ids with a subset of sector and category of the startig id, that is:

```
select * from T1 where id=10
```

return 2 records

The query i'm trying to write should return other ids with the same 2 records
even if they have other records. In this example this query should return only the id 20 because is a super set.

Many thanks

Comment: Is `NULL` possible in any of the columns? If so, how should it be treated? Then: can there be duplicates (two or more rows with the same `id`, same `category` and same `sector`)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you wnat all the rows with category and sectore selected using id 10

```
select t1.id from t1 
inner join (
  select  category, sector 
  from T1 where id=10 
) t on t.category = t1.category and t.sector = t1.sector
```

Comment: The OP wants to return IDs, not complete rows. He wants the ID's for which the set of pairs (category, sector) is a superset of the set of similar pairs for the input ID. Your solution doesn't seem to have anything to do with that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.id
from t join
     (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t t2
     ) t2
     on t2.category = t.category and t2.sector = t.sector and
        t2.id = 10
group by t.id
having count(*) = t2.cnt;
```

It first counts the number of rows for each id.  This is important for being sure that you have all of them.

Then, the query does a self-join on `category` and `sector`.  It aggregates by the first id and counts the matching rows.  If all match, then you keep the `id`.